# Multiple Javascript Variables in URLs

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with the following for the last 48 hours and I'm hoping someone here can dig me out of a hole;

`window.open("process.php?page=g&zipcode=" + zipcode);` <- I need to add a second variable to the end of this URL. I know that if I do this `window.open("process.php?page=g&zipcode=" + zipcode + id)`; adds the variable but annoyingly directly after the first one. What I need is for it to look like this:

```
process.php?page=g&zipcode=33001&id=63423563
```

the bit I can't get is how to add the "&id=" inbetween the variables.

I really hope that make sense.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only appending them directly, not adding the necessary string between them:

```
window.open('process.php?page=g&zipcode='+zipcode+'&id='+id);
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like I missed out the + after the first variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open("process.php?page=g&zipcode=" + zipcode + "&id=" +  id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` is used to concat  strings.

```
"process.php?page=g&zipcode=" + zipcode +"&id=" + id
```

Comment: Or as an addition operator ;)

Comment: You don't need a space before the &id= part

Comment: @BenM well it's strings addition :D

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `+` is used for both addition of numbers and concat of strings.
In your question you said that you have typed as,`window.open("process.php?page=g&zipcode=" + zipcode + id);`
This would concat the zipcode and id, and the combination to the string.Instead you must type,

```
window.open("process.php?page=g&zipcode=" + zipcode +"&id="+ id);
```

This would concat id to its respective string i.e.`&id=`.You have missed it to learn.